# ERROR: el nombre de tabla «Rides» fue especificado más de una vez SQL state: 42712

Tags: mysql, sql, update

Necesito que la columna de una tabla (Llamada Rides) quede igual que la columna de otra tabla (Histories). Para eso intento hacer este query; sin embargo, al momento de correr, me sale el siguiente error  "ERROR:  el nombre de tabla «Rides» fue especificado más de una vez SQL state: 42712"  Agradezvco me puedan ayudar

```
UPDATE "Rides" SET "Rides"."startDateTimeMs" = "Histories"."dateTimeMs"
FROM "Rides"
INNER JOIN "Histories"
ON "Rides".id = "Histories"."RideId"
where "Rides"."id" = 812467 and "Histories"."status" = 'in_place';
```

Answer (score 0):

Como no te esta aceptando el nombre de la tabla `Rides` tanto para el `UPDATE` como para el `FROM` que serían las secciones principales donde se esta invocando mas de una vez la misma entidad, entonces podemos darle un alias y posterior invocar así a las columnas; quedando de esta forma:

```
UPDATE Rides 
SET Rides.startDateTimeMs = Histories.dateTimeMs
FROM Rides AS Rd
INNER JOIN Histories ON Rd.id = Histories.RideId
where Rd.id = 812467 and Histories.status = 'in_place';
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta de la siguiente manera, no uses el from en la tabla que vas a actualizar porque marcara un error. Saludos

```
UPDATE "Rides" 
INNER JOIN "Histories" ON "Rides".id = "Histories"."RideId"
SET "Rides"."startDateTimeMs" = "Histories"."dateTimeMs"
where "Rides"."id" = 812467 and "Histories"."status" = 'in_place';
```